# Ideas for simple and useful AI for othello game (aka: reversi)

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, game-engine

Hi 
Where can I find some information for how to implement an AI for this game.
Never done an AI of any sort before.

Looking for recommendations for best and simple approaches
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negamax or minimax algorithm is simple and should work decently.

To get to a higher playing you'll need to add some heuristic, but a simple two move negamax is trivial to implement and fast.

Comment: which is simpler to implement Negamax or MinMax?Are there some sample code in C#?

Comment: They are very similar. Negamax is a bit nicer to implement. Just look into the wikipedia articles for them.

Comment: Negamax search is a slightly variant formulation of minimax search that relies on the zero-sum property of a two-player game.
This algorithm heavily relies on the fact that max(a, b) = -min(-a, -b) to simplify the implementation of the minimax algorithm.

Comment: @jv42 Why not? Negamax takes perhaps 10 lines and contains nothing conceptually difficult. Then you need a scoring function which in the simplest case is the difference between black/white stones on the board. And finally you need to be able to enumerate all valid moves which isn't hard either. The AI won't be very strong since the reading depth is low(perhaps 5 moves deep in a naive implementation before it gets too slow).

Comment: Well, the scoring function is hard to implement for starters, then you need to implement complex strategies for decent performance. I agree it's a relatively simple algorithm for a game AI though, just not easy for beginners.

Answer (score 11):

As in almost every board game you have to (a) evaluate how good a position is and (b) search for moves that lead to positions that are good for you.

Othello is slightly different from other games such as chess in that (a) is a little difficult. You can't easily tell which positions are good because the tables can turn very quickly. However, if you're just starting out, a good heuristic is

- Highly value taking corner fields
- Highly penalize taking the fields next to the corners
- Value other border tiles higher than remaining tiles
- Try to minimize the number of moves the opponent can make

For (b) you can use a standard game tree search algorithm such as [Minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) or [Alpha-Beta Pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning). There are many different ones to choose from.

Michael Buro, who wrote Logistello, one of the (formerly?) strongest othello playing programs, has written several fascinating papers about the subject. To tell how good a position is, he compares the patterns on the board (each rank, each file, all diagonals form patterns) with patterns in a database previously learned by the program. To search for desirable outcomes, he uses a search algorithm called Multi-Prob Cut.

Links that will probably be helpful:

- [Logistello Homepage](http://skatgame.net/mburo/log.html)
- [Othello on AITopics](http://aitopics.org/topic/othello).

Answer (score 2):

Russel/Norvig's "Artificial Intelligence - A modern approach" is a good starting point to learn about game theory, ai, heuristics and related stuff. Have a look here: http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually, Othello is an example for a game, where Minmax/Negamax does not work very well, because you need heuristics for evaluating intermediate game states which is difficult in Othello. Have a look at Monte Carlo Tree Search (MCTS). This should work well. Actually, I implemented a very simple mechanism inspired by MCTS myself and it beat all online AIs that I tested so far (while the AI makes a move within a very short time: 2sec).
The mechanism works as follows:
(a) get all possible moves for current player
(b) chose one of those at random
(c) alternately play the game with totally random (valid) moves until the game is over.
(d) value the game result
(e) add this value to the totalscore of the move chosen in step (b)
(f) add 1 to the number of visits for the move chosen in step (b)
(g) jump to (b) if there is time left (I gave the algorithm 2sec)
(h) make the move with highest average score (totalscore/number of visits)

Some optimizations are quite obvious, like making the move immediately, if there is only one that's valid or limiting the number of random simulations in addition to the time constraint (like 2000 per valid move or so).

Again, this is NOT MCTS, but merely the last part of MCTS, but it works quite well.

Greetings,
rattlehead

Comment: This is just a Monte-Carlo simulation algorithm. It's not MCTS because there is no tree. MCTS is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Source code is available [here](http://skatgame.net/mburo/log.html) for Logistello, which was the best game in town ten years ago.